# Почему нее выводит строку из файла?

Tags: файлы, строки, c++

```
char ch[255];

ifstream file("in.txt");  
file.getline(ch, sizeof(ch));
cout << ch;
file.close();
```

`in.txt`:

```
sdfsdfsf sd fd
dsfsdf dsfsd
```

Компилируется успешно, но ничего не выводит.

Comment: либо вы не открываете нужный файл (хотя это вряд ли, ибо должна вылетать ошибка), либо у вас в начале файла читается какой то нулевой символ, который за строку считается, что бы прочитать весь файл, либо читайте посимвольно через file.get(&char), либо читайте так же построчно, но в цикле while(!file.eof())

Comment: Вот завершается, а в консоль ничего не выводит? 

Наверное файл in.txt не в том каталоге.

Comment: @avp, in.txt лежит там же где и .exe

Comment: Нашёл! Дело в том, что запускал в дебаг режиме. А так норм всё.

Comment: @ололо, я быстренько скопопастил Ваш код и у меня он **работает** (только, естественно ньюлайн не выводит).

Comment: @ололо, хотите научиться писать программы?

Тогда выбросьте все IDE (лучше сразу вместе с виндой), пишите в редакторе, компилируйте вручную, а если программа из нескольких файлов, то пишите Makefile и запускайте тоже руками в терминале.

Comment: @avp, linux предлагаете?

Comment: Дебаг-режим тут не должен влиять. Вы бы проверяли, успешно ли файл открылся. Это нужно делать под любой системой :-) И ещё, лучше указывать абсолютный путь к файлу, а то мало ли откуда запустят вашу программу?

Comment: @ололо, конечно, любой \*nix. С Linux, наверное, сейчас проще всего. 

Если хотите, то можете поставить в винду виртуалку, например, VirtualBox а в ней для программирования Линукс.